# VSCode resolve import issue

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm having this strange issue using VSCode when I try to resolve a missing module (JS/TS): when I import a missing JS/TS module, it inserts the name of the imported module at the cursor's position, which breaks the variable name.

[image: VSCode import messing up]

What I want is to replace the variable name by the name of the imported module.

*I have reinstalled VSCode, deleted my settings.json, uninstalled all my plugins. I'm using VSCode on macOs.*

Comment: Try to only enable the Visual Studio Code IntelliSense plugin and see what happens?

Comment: Where can I find the Visual Studio Code IntelliSense plugin?

Comment: Refer to this link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode

Comment: It doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out **this is the default behavior of VS Code**.

To activate the "replace" option when importing module, you'll have to set:

`"editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"` into your `settings.json`